# Using ajax to send back JSON to Android nanoHTTPd function

Tags: java, android, ajax, android-studio, nanohttpd

Hey all I am trying to POST some json data to my android app via Jquery AJAX and using NanoHTTPd as the web server.

I can seem to call the correct url doing this:

```
var reqData = JSON.stringify({"AppName": "test", "Enabled": "yes" });

$.ajax('http://10.0.2.16:8765/data', {
   data: reqData,
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: "application/json",
   async: false,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      alert(data);
   },
   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("error:" + errorThrown + ' ' + reqData);
   }
});
```

Once I fire off that call above it goes to this java/nanoHTTPd code:

```
if (uri.equals("/data")) {
   try {
      session.parseBody(new HashMap<String, String>());

      System.out.println( session.getMethod() + " " + session.getParms() );

      String postBody = session.getQueryParameterString();
      String postParameter = session.getParms().get("AppName");

      return newFixedLengthResponse(
          NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.OK, 
          MIME_PLAINTEXT, 
          "It was good!"
      );
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND,"","ERROR");
   } catch (ResponseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND,"","ERROR");
   }
}
```

But I am getting **null** for the **postBody**? The `System.out.println` shows `I/System.out: POST {}`

The error alert for the ajax error part dispays like this:

[image]

What would I be missing here in order to get the post data ajax is sending?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  If this is an app, there are easier ways to call native code in the same process from Javascript.  If this is a unit test and you're mocking the server, you're better off running the http server on the host machine.  Running an HTTP server on an Android device is never a good idea, there's always better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out finally. I needed to format my javascript code like this:

```
var reqData = JSON.stringify({ data: { AppName: "test", Enabled: "yes" }});

$.ajax({
   url        : "http://10.0.2.16:8765/data",
   data       : reqData,
   dataType   : "json",
   crossDomain: true,
   type       : "POST"
   headers    : {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
   },             
   success    : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       $("#output").append("data: " + data.status);
   },
   error      : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       $("#output").append("error: " + errorThrown);
   }
});
```

And for the java code side using nanoHTTPd:

```
if (uri.equals("/data")) {
    try {
        if (session.getMethod().equals(Method.POST)) {
            session.parseBody(new HashMap<String, String>());
            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(session.getQueryParameterString());
            JSONObject uniObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("data");
            String appname = uniObject.getString("AppName");
            String isEnabled = uniObject.getString("Enabled");

            Response R = newFixedLengthResponse(NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.OK, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "{\"status\":\"It was good!\"}");

            R.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            R.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
            R.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

            return R;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND,"","ERROR");
    } catch (ResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND,"","ERROR");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

return  null;
```